# Domain class GORM methods for no sql database in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Being new to grails, Just wanted to understand, take inputs about domain classess.
Can these be used to map to nosql databases. And methods like save, update, delete be overridden to execute specific queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Please look at plugin `http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb` for example.

Answer (score 0):

not only mongo is provided via GORM. Thanks to the recent refactoring of the GORM plugin, it's now possible to wire-in pretty much any database out there. 
check [the GitHub](http://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping) out and see what plugins are available now.

CRUD operations shall be by default provided by any of GORM implementations.